# Access data from Firebase Service in main thread

Tags: android, firebase, event-handling, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am programming an app that receives some data from a FCM message, then updates the UI based on the data payload contained in the message.

The service runs fine, and receives the data, but I cant figure out how to get it back to my main activity.

The Firebase service is declared in my manifest as

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseService">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

In my MyFirebaseService class I have overridden the onMessageReceived method, but how am I supposed to notify my main activity that a message was received?

Is there a handler I can use with the Firebase service?

Comment: yup you can listen for intent come to main activity

Comment: i dont get what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dev.android.com > Develop > Training > Background Jobs > Reporting Work Status
```

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html

> To send the status of a work request in an IntentService to other
>   components, first create an Intent that contains the status in its
>   extended data.
>
> Next, send the Intent by calling
>   LocalBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(). This sends the Intent to any
>   component in your application that has registered to receive it.

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION).putExtra(DATA_STATUS, status);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
```

> To receive broadcast Intent objects, use a subclass of
>   BroadcastReceiver. In the subclass, implement the
>   `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` callback method, which
>   LocalBroadcastManager invokes when it receives an Intent.
>   LocalBroadcastManager passes the incoming Intent to
>   `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()`.
>
> To register the BroadcastReceiver and the IntentFilter with the
>   system, get an instance of LocalBroadcastManager and call its
>   `registerReceiver()` method.

```
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
     .registerReceiver(mDownloadStateReceiver, statusIntentFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my messaging handle

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", fcmTitle);
    intent.putExtra("summary", fcmSummary);
    intent.putExtra("message", fcmMessage);
    intent.putExtra("imageUrl", fcmImageUrl);
    intent.putExtra("goto", fcmGoto);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(App.getAppContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

you can have something like this to listen in main activity

```
Boolean bolGoto = false;
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            //String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
            if (key.equals("goto")){
                bolGoto = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (bolGoto){
        handleFCMNotification(getIntent());
    }
```