# why is this problem "Can't create handler inside thread" happening on realtime database?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, handler

so i'm trying to call realtime database from inside a firebasemessagingservice to get some infos from the database but each and every time the app is on background this error is happening

```
09-17 19:27:21.596 4083-4140/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-MyFirebaseMessagingService
    Process: com.kirtu.simpletexts.texts, PID: 4083
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
        at com.google.firebase.database.zza.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:1024)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:77)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzu.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:2234)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzad.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:92)
        at com.google.firebase.database.obfuscated.zzad.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:42)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:357)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getReference(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.2:201)
        at com.kirtu.simpletexts.texts.MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:60)
        at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzd(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzc.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

why is this problem happening suddenly?previously it never happened.

here is my code

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
...
...
...
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("xxxx").child(xxxx).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()//problem is happening at this line
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                        {
...
...
...
    }
});
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a Firebase bug.

Comment: Have you tried researching about `Looper.prepare()` method?

Comment: i'm researching it but i'm unable to understand what exactly to search,can u please give me some reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calls to the Firebase Realtime Database client are expected to be made from the main thread. More specifically, the Firebase client invokes the `onDataChange` callback on the main/UI thread of your app. Since `onMessageReceived` is part of a service, it may be called when the main/UI thread is not active. And, while I've never seen it before, the error message you get is the result when that happens.

The trick is to post from your `onMessagesReceived` to the main thread (see [Access data from Firebase Service in main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403990/access-data-from-firebase-service-in-main-thread)), or ensure that the looper is initialized so that your code can be called from the correct context (see [Firebase Cloud Messaging: Accessing UI elements in onMessageReceived()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035485/firebase-cloud-messaging-accessing-ui-elements-in-onmessagereceived)).

Answer (score 1):

solved it with the help of the answer by @Frank Van Puffelen

i just needed to put

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("xxxx").child(xxxx).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()//problem is happening at this line
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                        {
...
...
...
    }
});
```

inside

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

.....
.....
.....}
                        });
```

then it worked.